# Split string along into sections based on headlines

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string with several sections named "Section 1"..."Section 20" and want to split this string into these individual sections. Here is an example:

```
Stuff we don't care about

Section 1
Text within this section, may contain the word section.

And go on for quite a bit.

Section 15
Another section
```

I want to separate this into

```
["Section 1\n Text within this section, may contain the word section.\n\nAnd go in for quite a bit.",
"Section 15 Another section"]
```

I'm feeling quite stupid for not getting it right. My attempts always capture everything. Right now I have

```
/(Section.+\d+$[\s\S]+)/
```

But I can't get the greediness out of it.

Comment: Once you've encountered "Section 1", do you want to capture everything else? Or, is there text after Section 20 you want to ignore? Is the text you want to capture following a Section, *ALWAYS* the immediately-following line, or will there be paragraphs/blank lines between the sections?

Comment: The example is pretty clear. He wants an array with each section (header + text) as its elemetns.

Comment: has the answer been helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scan` with this regexp `/Section\s\d+\n(?:.(?!Section\s\d+\n))*/m`

```
string.scan(/Section\s\d+\n(?:.(?!Section\s\d+\n))*/m)
```

`Section\s\d+\n` will match any Section header

`(?:.(?!Section\s\d+\n))*` will match anything else, except another section header.

`m` will make dots match newlines too

```
sample = <<SAMPLE 
Stuff we don't care about

Section 1
Text within this section, may contain the word section.

And go on for quite a bit.

Section 15
Another section
SAMPLE

sample.scan(/Section\s\d+\n(?:.(?!Section\s\d+\n))*/m)
#=> ["Section 1\nText within this section, may contain the word section.\n\nAnd go on for quite a bit.\n", "Section 15\nAnother section\n"]
```

Answer (score 1):

In my view the `Regexp` to split the text is the following:

```
/(?:\n\n|^)Section/
```

So the code is:

```
str = "
Stuff we don't care about

Section 1
Text within this section, may contain the word section.

And go on for quite a bit.

Section 15
Another section
"

newstr = str.split( /(?:\n\n|^)Section/, -1 )[1..-1].map {|l| "Section " + l.strip }
# => ["Section 1\nText within this section, may contain the word section.\n\nAnd go on for quite a bit.", "Section 15\nAnother section"]
```

Comment: Sorry, the text within each section is more complicated and may contain newlines etc. I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex:

```
(?m)(Section\s*\d+)(.*?\1)$
```

[Live demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/kPI0TUzWyW)

Comment: I'ts not working properly. I'ts ignoring "another section" at the end  and giving weird matches

Comment: @robertodecurnex You mistaken. "Another section" means "Section 16" for example, and it works though.

Comment: no, just took the sample and used your link -> http://www.rubular.com/r/euxXwqo03d

Comment: @robertodecurnex OP made a mistake in section naming I think. It's not Section 1 but Section 15, so this way it can be split into indivisual parts.

Comment: It doesn't really matter the section number. It's just common section headers + content. The use of \1 looks clever but do not apply for this scenario. If you want to prevent the repetition of that fragment you should probably split the regexp in 2 and use regexp compositions

Comment: @robertodecurnex each section begins with `Section X` and ends to `Section X`. That's what I got from OP.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing is:

```
str = "Stuff we don't care about

Section 1
Text within this section, may contain the word section.

And go on for quite a bit.

Section 15
Another section"

str[/^Section 1.+/m] # => "Section 1\nText within this section, may contain the word section.\n\nAnd go on for quite a bit.\n\nSection 15\nAnother section"
```

If you're breaking sections at the `Section` headers, start the same way, then take advantage of Enumerable's [`slice_before`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before):

```
str = "Stuff we don't care about

Section 1
Text within this section, may contain the word section.

And go on for quite a bit.

Section 15
Another section"

str[/^Section 1.+/m].split("\n").slice_before(/^Section \d+/m).map{ |a| a.join("\n") }
# => ["Section 1\nText within this section, may contain the word section.\n\nAnd go on for quite a bit.\n",
#     "Section 15\nAnother section"]
```

The `slice_before` docs say:

> Creates an enumerator for each chunked elements. The beginnings of chunks are defined by pattern and the block.

Comment: No. note that there is a comma on the right of the first line. There are 2 elements in the example.

Comment: That only makes it easier. Thanks.